# Run two dependent commands in background

Tags: linux, background-process

I need to execute two commands in the background

```
function "$arg1" "$agr2" arg3 && declare "workspaces=$arg3"
```

first it will execute function if it complete then it will initialize arg3 in workspace(it is global var) and whole process should run in background

I tried

```
function "$arg1" "$agr2" arg3 && declare "workspaces=$arg3" & //this didn't work
(function "$arg1" "$agr2" arg3 && declare "workspaces=$arg3") & //niether this
```

I don't want to execute both in parallel because in this case workspace will not initialize

Comment: Can you provide more information about what this function is doing and what are `arg[1-3]` ?

Comment: @mrc02_kr function calling another script that is taking more time and args are simply string variables like arg1="file1 file2 file3" and arg2="file1" and arg3=""

Comment: Try, `function "$arg1" "$agr2" arg3 & declare "workspaces=$arg3" &`

Comment: or `(function "$arg1" "$agr2" arg3 &) && (declare "workspaces=$arg3" &)`

Comment: It didn't work arg3 values is null in this case for (declare "workspaces=$arg3" &)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're running into is that you're expecting the global variable `$workspaces` to be set as a result of this function. However, you can't set a global variable (in shell terms, an `export`) on the current shell from a subshell. And the only way you can run a command in background is by running it in a subshell. Therefore, running `declare` or `export` as part of a background command will not set that variable in the current shell, which seems to be what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It is really unclear to me what you are trying to do.

My guess is that you can use `parset` from GNU Parallel as part of the solution:

```
# Activate parset
. `which env_parallel.bash`

export -f myfunction
parset myresult -j0 myfunction {} ::: arg1 arg2 arg3
echo "${myresult[0]}"
echo "${myresult[1]}"
echo "${myresult[2]}"
```

This will run these commands in parallel:

```
myfunction arg1
myfunction arg2
myfunction arg3
```

and put the output from each of them in the array `myresult`.